# api extract country whit regex from html

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture country of my clients whit this api : http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=

I need regex to capture only the country.

I have made this :

```
Country\:.+\x28
```

That is not good I need extract only the country name.

Comment: The API you are using has the option to send results back in XML or JSON formats. One of those, not HTML + regex, is the right way to get this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression should work:
`Country: ([\w\s]+) \(\w+\)`

It matches on a string of one or more alphanumerical characters or whitespace followed by a set of one or more alphanumerical characters in brackets and captures the first group.

```
>>> import re
>>> import requests
>>> country_line = requests.get("http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=8.8.8.8").content.splitlines()[0]
>>> re.match(r"Country: ([\w\s]+) \(\w+\)", country_line).group(1)
'UNITED STATES'
```